# Getting Py4JavaError:Calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext

Tags: flask, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I have posted this question as "How to solve Py4JavaError: Calling None.org.apache .spark.java.javaSparkContext". by misunderstanding  a user have flagged it duplicate.so i am again posting this question with different name.

I am trying to build a flask-spark application using pyspark. For testing purpose I will give a sqlstring in url which will be process in Spark script and will return json data to the browser as response.Here is my code.

```
import re
from tkinter import*
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from flask import Flask
#from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
#conf=SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName("TestValue")
#sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
#sqlContext=HiveContext(sc)
#from pyspark.sql import Row
import json



app=Flask(__name__)
spark=SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:\spark\spark-warehouse").appName("TestApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
print("Success")

#sqlstring="SELECT lflow1.LeaseType as LeaseType, lflow1.Status as Status, lflow1.Property as property, lflow1.City as City, lesflow2.DealType as DealType, lesflow2.Area as Area, lflow1.Did as DID, lesflow2.MID as MID from lflow1, lesflow2  WHERE lflow1.Did = lesflow2.MID"
@app.route('/<sqlval>')
def queryBuilder(sqlval):
    df=spark.sql(sqlval)
    #df.show()

    resultlist = df.toJSON().collect()
    dumpdata = re.sub(r"\'", "", str(resultlist))
    jsondata = json.dumps(dumpdata)
    #print(jsondata)
    return jsondata

    #return df

#queryBuilder(sqlstring)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)

master=Tk()
entryval=Entry(master)
entryval.grid(row=0,column=1)
Button(master,text='Quit',command=master.quit).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W,pady=50)
mainloop()


#print("Type",type(jsondata))
```

here the sqlstring will come from browser url in localhost and access into querybuilder function which will return json data to browser as response . when i am running spark submit this error has occur

[image]

**py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at: org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)**

i have read some post regarding this. People used both sparksession and sqlcontext  for achieving result and they have got this error. Experts have encouraged not to use both but use either  Sparksession or SqlContext .Spark session gives all functionalities in spark 2.0 or later.I have done this code by SparkSession.May be i am missing some configuration here. kindly help me to figure it out how could i configure Sparksession to avoid this error.